# swiftlint open brace rule

Tags: regex, swift, swiftlint

I'm using Swiftlint to enforce some practices in our codebase. I want to add a custom rule that makes sure a `{` always appears after a newline. I thought I knew regexes, but can't seem to figure it out. I just check if a line contains any characters other than whitespace before the `{`. It is allowed to have stuff after the `{`.

What I have now:

```
invalid_open_brace:
    name: "Open brace should start on its own line"
    regex: "(\S+.*\{)"
    message: "Open brace should start on its own line"
    severity: warning
```

Here are some example strings that should and should not match:

```
// NO MATCH
else if let var1 = var1 as? String, !var1.isEmpty 
{

//NO MATCH
class Person
{
    // MATCH
    int() 
    {
    }

    // NO MATCH
    function() 
    {

    }
 }

// MATCH
function() {

}
```

Comment: Characters other than `\S` before `{` means you need to use `"\\s[{]"` (check if there is a whitespace before `{`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated my question. I want to matches lines that contain a { with some else then whitespace before them.

Comment: Good, then use `"\\S[{]"` (or `"\\S\\{"`) (note that double ecape is necessary when used as a string literal).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when i type ur solution in https://regex101.com/ with content:                 else if let var1 = var1 as? String,
                        !var1.isEmpty {. Nothing gets highlighted

Comment: Nothing will, since `\S\{` matches in `.isEmpty{`. You say you need to match only if there is anything other than whitespace before `{`. Please reconsider your requirements, and update your question.

Comment: But than my question isn't clear yet. I want to match { when they are not a newline. So the open brace should be on a newline not after isEmpty

Comment: Try `\\S[\r\n]+\\{` (or `\\S\\R+\\{`) to match a non-whitespace, line break chars, `{`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2AWyC5/1) - is that what you need to match?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/2AWyC5/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could u check my comments in https://regex101.com/r/2AWyC5/2

Comment: And what are the *requirements*? What is the difference between `!var1.isEmpty<LBR>{` and `Person<LBR>{`? Why shouldn't the first one match and the second should?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137637/discussion-between-scarecrow-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `(\S+.*\{)` regex matches any char that is not  whitespace (one or more reptitions - `\S+`), then any char other than linebreak (*including non-whitespaces* - here is the root cause of your issue), and `{`.

You may use

```
\S[ \t]+\{
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OfDAtp/1).

**Details**:

- `\S` - any non-whitespace char
- `[ \t]+` - one or more (`+`) **horizontal** whitesapces (can be replaced with `[\t\p{Zs}]+` where `\p{Zs}` matches all horizontal Unicode whitespace without a tab).
- `\{` - a literal `{` symbol.

Comment: Thank you very much. The amount of effort and explanations are great!